# как посчитать количество чисел в массиве java введенных с клавиатуры?

Tags: java

Задача.

1. Ввести с клавиатуры неопределенное количество элементов(цифер). Используя BufferedReader.
2. Составить массив из этих чисел.
3. Посчитать количество элементов(чисел) в массиве.
4. Сложить элементы и найти среднеарифметическое значение.

Не могу никак понять, как сделать так, чтобы количество элементов в массиве не было установлено заранее, а зависело от количество введенных с клавиатуры элементов.

Comment: [ArrayList](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/klass-arraylist) в помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Write numbers separate them by space: ");

    double count = 0;
    String numbers = reader.readLine();
    List<Double> nums = Arrays.stream(numbers.split("\\s"))
        .map(Double::parseDouble)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    for (Double num : nums) {
        count += num;
    }

    System.out.println(count/nums.size());
```

Вот пример кода , не очень хороший но работает, при условии что после каждого элемента введен пробел . при ипользовании List, ArrayList необязательно задавать какое-то число можно просто добавить элементов сколько хочешь .

[Вот](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-vs-arraylist-in-java/) хорошая статья надеюсь поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Задача наверное подталкивает к использованию новых структур данных, в данном случае так называемых динамических массивов. Можно в примеру использовать **ArrayList** или **LinkedList**. Ну а насчет неопределенного количества, думаю там должен быть какой-то стоп символ. Как-то так )